# Asp Button hover and CSS

Tags: asp.net, css

I have an asp button control on which i have applied some style. I want that on hover of this button, the colour of the button should change or something of that sort.
But I fail to understand why in CSS the button hover function is not working!!
PLease help. Also please let me know what are the best effects we can have for a button hover.

```
    <asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" CssClass="button"  OnClick="btnSearch_Click"     Style="width: 480px;" Text="Search" />

.button
{
    background: white;
    border: solid 1px grey;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #001563;    
    height: 25px;  

}

.button:hover
{
    background: white;
    border: solid 1px grey;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: Red;   
    height: 25px;

}
```

Comment: you see this in every browser or just IE?

Answer (score 7):

Please check the following code:

```
 <asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" OnClick="btnSearch_Click"  Style="width: 480px;" CssClass="button" Text="Search" />
      <style type="text/css">
.button
{
    background: white;
    border: solid 1px grey;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #001563;    
    height: 25px;  

}

.button:hover
{
    background: white;
    border: solid 1px grey;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: Red;   
    height: 25px;

}</style>
```

Comment: I have checked the above code putting the css in aspx page and it is working fine. Have you put the .button css class in your css file or in the page? If you r using css file then please make sure Your page is accessing the css file.

Comment: Remember don't do any styling for control through properties, just apply css class.

Answer (score 1):

asp:buttons render as HTML input (submit button) tags, so you can't use the same CSS syntax as a hyperlink.

This should work in browsers (except MSIE):

(note: "button" is your class name)

```
input.button:hover{
   color: Green;
}
```

or to change all submit buttons:

```
input[type="submit"]:hover{
   color: Green;
}
```

If you Google for CSS techniques of doing hover on buttons (input buttons), then you'll find some better CSS and JavaScript techniques.

Answer (score 0):

Let the style of the button be decided by the operating system. It would be bette not to try modifying this behavior. Most of the times you won't be successful.

The :hover pseudo-class applies while the user designates an element (with some pointing device), but does not activate it. For example, a visual user agent could apply this pseudo-class when the cursor (mouse pointer) hovers over a box generated by the element. User agents not supporting interactive media do not have to support this pseudo-class. Some conforming user agents supporting interactive media may not be able to support this pseudo-class (e.g., a pen device).

See [Selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#dynamic-pseudo-classes)

If you want to apply hover effect to a button then better use an anchor tag and use an image inside that.

```
a:hover { }
```

Comment: Thanks Phoenix. Can you explain by giving an example?

Comment: If you need to style like that of a button then make an image that looks like a button and in the :hover pseudo class change the style using a:hover.

Comment: That is the last option.
But dont we have another way if we dont want to design an image?
Cant we change the button color through hover property of CSS?